# Force hippie-expand to respect capitalization

Tags: emacs

I want to stop hippie-expand from giving me completions that don't match the capitalization that I've already provided. Examples:

```
start with "hippie1", "Hippie2", and "HIPPIE3"

"H" completes to "Hippie2" and "HIPPIE3", but not "hippie1"
```

Is there an easy way to make this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`hippie-expand` farms out the work to the functions in `hippie-expand-try-functions-list`, and I think it is up to each individual function as to whether or not it considers case to be significant, so there might not be a simple solution?

Experimentally, the `case-fold-search` variable is effective in some cases, but not all.

edit:
Well this *isn't* a definitive solution to the stated question, however if setting `case-fold-search` is sufficient for your purposes, you can use the following:

```
(defadvice hippie-expand (around hippie-expand-case-fold)
  "Try to do case-sensitive matching (not effective with all functions)."
  (let ((case-fold-search nil))
    ad-do-it))
(ad-activate 'hippie-expand)
```

Comment: `case-fold-search` seems to work for me as well. Unfortunately, I really like having case insensitive search so this isn't a great solution. I'll keep playing around with it and report back.

Comment: Answer updated. This is one of the reasons why dynamic binding was such a great design decision for Emacs :)

Comment: So I've been using this for a while, and it seems to solve the problem perfectly. Feels like a complete hack, but like you said - that's why dynamic binding was such a great design decision. Thanks!